# Update List Item Selector

Tags: android, listview, selector, listitem

I have 2 views one below the other :

```
<Button />
<ListView />
```

The list view has item defined in xml and its inflated in the Adapter.

list_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
 android:id="@+id/rowView"   
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
 android:padding="5dp"  
 android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
 android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector"
 android:textSize="16sp" >  
</TextView>
```

in the Adapter :

```
   if (convertView == null) {
                        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                    }

    ....etc...
```

Now the you can see that the `list_item.xml` `textview` has selectors added to it.
The `Button` which is above the `ListView` has a `onClick` to it, onclick i need to remove those selectors and replace with some other color.

How can i do this ?

**EDIT**

We can refresh the Adapter onClick but list view is blank(something like visibility is INVISIBLE), but when i touch that view it again shows up.

Comment: android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
 android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector"
you want to remove these two attributes and want to add your own colors is that you are trying to ask ?

Comment: It should be onItemClick instead of onClick right?

Comment: @Darkie Yes, say i have selected a item in the listview and its highlighted with selector(RED), now onclick of button i want to remove that and set it with default color(WHITE)

Comment: Is the list is in multi selection mode?

Comment: @EagleEye No SINGLE_CHOICE_MODE

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listView.setSelector(R.color.white);

        }
    });
```

EDT:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No we need to bring the listview to orginal state, like first time its loaded with all the items

Comment: The code above does the same thing. have you tried the above code? Whats the result?

Comment: I have tried this before it wont work, because we have not set selector to listview.